# Intent sent by Google app to WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, intents

I have some very basic knowledge regarding the working of intents. I am a user of Tasker. Even after a lot of searching, I could not find any intent using which I could send a WhatsApp message.
But, as we all know, the Google app using some method to send WhatsApp messages when we say * Send a WhatsApp message to XYZ*. How does the Google app do this?

Comment: Are you asking as a developer trying to send an intent to WhatsApp? If so, questions about writing and publishing Android apps and other topics that are primarily of concern to developers are off-topic on Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: No @Charles Caldwell , I am not a developer. I myself am a techno-geek with some knowledge of Tasker

Comment: You can find answers on WhatsApp sento intent here: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012 or here: [Send text to specific contact programmatically (whatsapp)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19081654/5374691)

Comment: May I suggest you using our fine search engine with the terms [whatsapp intent](/search?q=whatsapp+intent)? [How does Google app interact with WhatsApp?](/q/173294/16575) confirms your guess on intents, and [WhatsApp Intent](/q/185284/16575) covers your Tasker question.